# Graphic cards for Ubuntu 19.10 that support hardware encoding

Tags: graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, 19.10, encoding

I got a computer that came with a Radeon R7 240 Graphics card. I want to use the computer to livestream to youtube. (Not streaming games, just general discussions). I'm setting up OSB Studio and doing experiments to see what settings result in the best quality video, but through the process it looks like my video card may not be capable of encoding video.

Is that the case?
Do I need a better video card or has this problem been resolved and I just haven't found the answer yet? And if I do need a new video card, what options do I have that will do what I need and work out of the box with Ubuntu 19.10?

System specs:

- 3.5 GHz Ryzen 3 2300U
- RAM 8 GB DDR4
- Memory Speed 2400 MHz
- Hard Drive 1 TB Hybrid Drive
- Graphics Coprocessor Radeon R7 240
- Chipset Brand AMD
- Card Description Dedicated
- Graphics Card Ram Size 2 GB
- Wireless Type 802.11ac
- OS: Ubuntu 19.10
- OSB version: 24.0.3 (64 bit)

vainfo:

```
clay@Darth-Buntu:~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.5.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_5
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.5 (libva 2.5.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Mesa Gallium driver 19.2.1 for AMD OLAND (DRM 2.50.0, 5.3.0-24-generic, LLVM 9.0.0)
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
VAProfileMPEG2Simple : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileMPEG2Main : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileVC1Simple : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileVC1Main : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileVC1Advanced : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264Main : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264High : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileNone : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

Comment: There's a November 2019 driver from AMD; are you using it? https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-lin-19-30-unified and   https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-r7-series/amd-radeon-r7-200-series/amd-radeon-r7-240

Answer (score 1):

It may be while your encoding its not using your GPU. I believe it uses ffmpeg to encode. You'd have to look there how to make it use your GPU or check if it is already using your GPU.

See this link: [How to use GPU acceleration in FFmpeg with AMD Radeon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107782/how-to-use-gpu-acceleration-in-ffmpeg-with-amd-radeon)

Then youd have to make sure that OBS uses those commands. Worst case scenario you could just write a script with the appropriate flags, chmod +x. Then tell obs studio to use your script instead of the system ffmpeg.

There are many claims online that using the AMD official drivers nets you better performance. However the AMD drivers only support Ubuntu 18.04.3.

If you'd like to use the official AMD Drivers you'll want to do the following:

- Download Ubuntu 18.04.3
- Download the latest AMD Drivers (Note: They
  only work with Ubuntu 18.04.3) You can get them here
  https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-lin-19-50-unified
- To install the AMD Drivers use the following command

  ```
  ./amdgpu-install --opencl=legacy
  ```

If you do not use the --opencl=legacy flags, your GPU will not accelerate any applications.

Good Luck.

edit: corrected my failure of actually understanding the question.
      added ffmpeg info for AMD radeon encoding, which is what OBS uses to 
      encode.